# What is the least energy trajectory in Astronomy?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

Hi I wanted to know what the least energy trajectory is in relation to astronomy as I can't seem to find a good answer on Google. I want to know because I am trying to answer this question:

> A space probe is put into orbit around the sun with semi major axis of
>   $2AU$. How long in years does it take to orbit the sun once? If it
>   travelled directly in a least energy trajectory, how long would it
>   take the space probe to get from earth to it's new orbit ?

I believe I have done the first step which is use keplers 3$^{\text{rd}}$ law so

$$T = \sqrt{2^3} = 2.82$$ years but I have no idea what the least energy trajectory is in order to finish the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the Hohmann transfer.  I find this [pdf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://earthweb.ess.washington.edu/ess-102/FALL12/Lecture28_PlanetaryMotionandOrbitalMechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjbtK63-vPfAhUQzaQKHXbEDBsQFjAGegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw2O2U_x4Ez-2Mu7jFmOOKVh)
that explains the idea with some examples and maybe you can find more by searching.